# For MySQL, I need a report of rows more than 1 standard deviation from average in percent

Tags: mysql, database, math

I'm trying to write a MySQL query to calculate the rows that are much different than the most common for each product and report percent difference where under 100% is lower priced than average for that product and over 100% is higher priced. Ignoring prices that are less than 1 standard deviation from average.

Sample data:

| _rowid | _timestamp | code | fk_product_id | fk_po_id | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5952 | 2021-01-10 10:19:01 | 00805 | 1367 | 543 | 0.850 |
| 9403 | 2022-05-23 14:54:34 | 00805 | 1367 | 2942 | 0.850 |
| 41595 | 2022-11-23 11:20:26 | 00805 | 1367 | 3391 | 1.350 |
| 39635 | 2022-01-18 12:49:32 | Water1 | 344 | 3153 | 0.140 |
| 40134 | 2022-04-06 22:39:34 | Water1 | 344 | 2747 | 0.190 |
| 41676 | 2022-12-09 16:28:28 | Water1 | 344 | 3398 | 0.140 |
| 39634 | 2022-01-18 12:49:31 | gr309203 344400 | 1024 | 3154 | 0.770 |
| 35634 | 2021-03-03 15:23:23 | gr309203 344400 | 1024 | 3203 | 0.790 |
| 41264 | 2022-11-16 11:41:44 | gr309203 344400 | 1024 | 3357 | 0.970 |

```
SELECT code, fk_product_id, cost, cost/
  (SELECT avg(cost) FROM po_line aa WHERE aa.code = code) AS percent 
FROM po_line 
WHERE (SELECT STDDEV(cost) FROM po_line ss WHERE ss.code = code)>1;
```

This doesn't return any rows, but there are three lines (one for each product) that should show in the report.

The expected result should be:

| code | fk_product_id | cost | percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00805 | 1367 | 1.350 | 133 |
| Water1 | 344 | 0.190 | 121 |
| gr309203 344400 | 1024 | 0.970 | 115 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query shows how to use window functions to calculate the number of standard deviations and the percentage of cost relative to the average cost for each given code.

```
SELECT code, cost, avg, std, 
  ABS(cost-avg)/std AS num_std, 
  cost*100/avg AS pct
FROM (
  SELECT code, cost,
    AVG(cost) OVER (PARTITION BY code) AS avg,
    STDDEV(cost) OVER (PARTITION BY code) AS std
  FROM po_line
) AS p;
```

Result:

```
+-----------------+-------+-----------+---------------------+--------------------+-------------+
| code            | cost  | avg       | std                 | num_std            | pct         |
+-----------------+-------+-----------+---------------------+--------------------+-------------+
| 00805           | 0.850 | 1.0166667 | 0.23570226039551592 | 0.7071069226079035 |  83.6065546 |
| 00805           | 0.850 | 1.0166667 | 0.23570226039551592 | 0.7071069226079035 |  83.6065546 |
| 00805           | 1.350 | 1.0166667 | 0.23570226039551592 | 1.4142134209517383 | 132.7868809 |
| gr309203 344400 | 0.770 | 0.8433333 |  0.0899382504215469 | 0.8153738777025533 |  91.3043514 |
| gr309203 344400 | 0.790 | 0.8433333 |  0.0899382504215469 | 0.5929990827042229 |  93.6758930 |
| gr309203 344400 | 0.970 | 0.8433333 |  0.0899382504215469 | 1.4083740722807512 | 115.0197674 |
| Water1          | 0.140 | 0.1566667 | 0.02357022603955158 | 0.7071081954001099 |  89.3616831 |
| Water1          | 0.190 | 0.1566667 | 0.02357022603955158 | 1.4142121481595331 | 121.2765699 |
| Water1          | 0.140 | 0.1566667 | 0.02357022603955158 | 0.7071081954001099 |  89.3616831 |
+-----------------+-------+-----------+---------------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

(Note that window functions require MySQL 8.0).

That query just shows you how the calculations are done. To get the result you want:

```
SELECT code, fk_product_id, cost, ROUND(cost*100/avg) AS pct
FROM (
  SELECT code, cost, fk_product_id,
    AVG(cost) OVER (PARTITION BY code) AS avg,
    STDDEV(cost) OVER (PARTITION BY code) AS std
  FROM po_line
) AS p
WHERE ABS(cost-avg)/std > 1;

+-----------------+---------------+-------+------+
| code            | fk_product_id | cost  | pct  |
+-----------------+---------------+-------+------+
| 00805           |          1367 | 1.350 |  133 |
| gr309203 344400 |          1024 | 0.970 |  115 |
| Water1          |           344 | 0.190 |  121 |
+-----------------+---------------+-------+------+
```